# Which C++ pitfalls would arise if an implicit "__return_inherited_this" was available?

Tags: c++

I (possibly) need to create an extension to my C++ compiler, but I have first to ensure the idea is not a failure by design.

Let's start with the very beginning, in the world of C++ it is well known that it may be clever to return a reference to the `*this` object when leaving some functions. This allows to chain the calls, which is typically convenient for operator overloading, though it may also be useful for other regular member functions.
However, there are some limitations with the inheritance mechanics :

```
struct Cat {

    Cat &chain_me() {return *this;}

};

struct Nyan : Cat {

    Nyan &chain_me_more() {return *this;}

};

int main() {

    // Example of chained functions that works
    Nyan().chain_me_more().chain_me();

    // Example of chained functions that doesn't work
    Nyan().chain_me().chain_me_more();

}
```

In this example, the last line is invalid, because the function `Nyan::chain_me_more()` cannot be chain-called after `Cat::chain_me()`, since it returns a reference to the object `Nyan` as having the type `Cat`.

To avoid this problem, the developer who provides the classes must write a specific redirector for each parent function involved, in every derived classes. So in the example above, the following line must be added in the declaration of `Nyan` :

```
// Redirector for "Cat::chain_me()" in "Nyan"
Nyan &chain_me() {return static_cast<Nyan&>(Cat::chain_me());}
```

This is a very tedious task when working on a more complex set of classes that declares many functions, and the resulting code is harder to update later due to the risk of missing one of the redirector to modify.

Writing the function in the base class as a template taking a parameter `typename T` and returning `static_cast<T&>(*this)` cannot work, and I neither found a way to create a fully templated class to be inherited that would provide the expected effect. (Nevertheless I'm not a template genius, so I may have missed some magic tricks...)

In fact, a keyword like `__return_inherited_this` as an extension to the C++ could be a very simple solution, because the `Cat` class would only have to declare something like :

```
chain_me() {__return_inherited_this;}
```

This keyword would do what it says, the function should still return a `Cat&`, but it might be automatically cast to a derived `Nyan&` depending on how it is called, which is why I didn't put a return type. This is inspired from the constructor syntax that declares no return value, but actually behaves like a reference.

And in fact, the things may be even simpler. There is no need for a keyword since the lack of return type could already indicate the intention to supply the special reference :

```
chain_me() {}
```

Depending on the implementation, this may also match the natural way to compile into ASM. When the `thiscall` convention uses a register for the "this" pointer, the bytecode just have to preserve its value, and the function calls can be directly chained without doing anything else than passing the other arguments into the stack or registers. So both the compiled assembly and the C++ source couln't have to do anything to trigger the feature, which seems kind of consistent to me.

Here is an exemple of code using this extension idea :

```
struct Cat {

    chain_me() {}

};

struct Nyan : Cat {

    chain_me_more() {}

};

int main() {

    // Here "chain_me" is called from a Nyan, so it returns a Nyan& and our previous problem is solved
    Nyan nyan = Nyan().chain_me().chain_me_more();

    // Here "chain_me" is called from a Cat, so it returns a "Cat&"
    Cat cat = Cat().chain_me();

    // For obvious reasons, the magic cannot and must not apply to polymorphism
    Cat* ptr = &nyan;

    // Here "chain_me" is called from a Cat*, so it returns a Cat& and cannot call "chain_me_more()", the compilation fails
    ptr->chain_me().chain_me_more();

}
```

I did some tests of this concept in the past, but only with ugly scripts that converted the source code into standard C++, and I'm not sure the procedure was bugproof. Moreover, all compilation errors gave the line numbers and file names of the converted code, not the one effectively developed.

I currently would like to write a real compiler extension, but what if some C++ language rules I didn't though about were incompatible with my intended feature ? This is why I am coming here, to explain this idea and ask if somebody sees something wrong with it. I see no pitfall yet, but I am not a specialist of the standards, and it is clear that I wouldn't want to start this kind of work if there is a direct incompatibility with another feature of the C++.

Thanks for reading, here is another example of use before I leave this message :

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// ===========================
// Class representing a person

class Person {

    public:

        // Getter and setter for name
        const std::string &getName() const {return _name;}
        setName(const std::string &name) {_name = name;}

        // Getter and setter for description
        const std::string &getDesc() const {return _desc;}
        setDesc(const std::string &desc) {_desc = desc;}

        // Getter and setter for annual wage
        int getWage() const {return _wage;}
        setWage(int wage) {_wage = wage;}

        // Setter for all things related to the identity
        setIdentity(const std::string &name, const std::string &desc) {setName(name).setDesc(desc);}

    private:

        std::string _name;
        std::string _desc;

        int _wage = 0;

};

// =============================
// Class representing a customer

class Customer : public Person {

    public:

        // Getter and setter for the order count
        int getOrd() const {return _ord;}
        setOrd(int ord) {_ord = ord;}

        // Getter and setter for the debt
        int getDebt() const {return _debt;}
        setDebt(int debt) {_debt = debt;}

        // Setter for all things related to business, the extension allows to set wage first
        setBusiness(int wage, int ord, int debt) {setWage(wage).setOrd(ord).setDebt(debt);}

        // A super secret function to run on the client data
        executeSecretCode() {/* Format data here to sell it to some Tech Giants later */}

    private:

        int _ord = 0;
        int _debt = 0;

};

// =============
// Main function

int main() {

    // Create the database of customers, the extension allows to call the setters in any order
    std::vector<Customer> db;
    db.push_back(Customer().setBusiness(91000, 2, 500).setIdentity("Alice", "The very first person ever").executeSecretCode());
    db.push_back(Customer().setWage(76000).setIdentity("Bob", "The very second person ever").executeSecretCode());
    db.push_back(Customer().setBusiness(55000, 1, 160).setName("Clara"));

}
```

Comment: Newsflash: it appears that the wheel you've just reinvented is called [deduced this](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0847r7.html) in C++23.

Comment: Indeed this exactly looks like what I need! Though I had to read several times some sections of the chapter 4 to figure out how it would work: So a member function declared `template<typename T> T &fn(this T* self) {return *self;}` would do the job? This is a little more verbose than what I intended, but the feature is very complete, since it allows to do many more things. Thanks, with that upcoming "Deducing this" I guess I should not develop any extension and just wait for the compilers to update... I look forward it!

Comment: @Morgana should be `this T&& self`. You kind of can make a single-method CRTP by that

Comment: Oh I see, we are reusing the output of a function that returned a reference, so we don't declare T as being a pointer. (Would have it been the case with `template<typename T> T* fn(this T* self) {return self;}`?)

Comment: wouldn't be able to deduce. this keyword here is a special constraint describing that followed type-id should be matching the type of left-hand operand for `operator.` or dereferenced left operand of `operator->` where this function was the right-hand operand. You can have an overload `Cat fn(this Cat self)` which would be called ONLY for `Cat`. You'd have to call function explicitily (not legal) to work around, like `catptr->Cat::chain_me<Cat*>();` That's must be illegal because such syntax is already reserved for dual inheritance resolution.

Answer (score 4):

C++23 kind of implements it as a possible use of this-deduction

```
struct Cat {
    template <class Self>
    auto&& chain_me(this Self&& self) {
        return std::forward<Self>(self);
    }
};

struct Displacer : Cat  {};

void main() {
   std::cout << typeid(Displacer().chain_me()).name() << std::endl;
}
```

It's obviously not type-erasure friendly in this form, and it makes source code DRY at cost of compiler getting a WET end of it.

Comment: Thank you for the code example, I first wondered why we had to use the `&&` operator, but after thinking a little this is probably due to the possibility to have a temporary object like in the `Displacer().chain_me()` of your example. Isn't it?

Comment: @Morgana Or if it was a const object.  It's a template , `Self` is a template formal argument, so `Self&&` is forwarding reference which turns `self` into an expression with a correct value cathegory.

Answer (score 3):

Chaining via explicit return is manually writing code to permit a syntactic feature.

The compiler knows better than the implementor of a function the type and identity of the object invoking a method.  Forcing the impelmentor to return that specific object to allow a specific technique at the call site looks like a DRY violation.

And that is what you are avoiding.

I would be tempted to use the `this` keyword however.  We already see this in "explicit this" first argument.

```
struct nyat{
  this chain_me()const{}
};
```

which says it returns this.

Return from such a method must be void.

At call site, it permits chaining.

```
nyat foo;
foo.chain_me().chain_me();
```

gets rewritten as

```
auto&& tmp=foo; tmp.chain_me(), tmp.chain_me();
```

The only traps are if the method deletes this: but if you have to mark such methods up explicitly it should make the problem obvious.

That does make me want to force a `return this;`: makes `delete this; return this;` stick out more, and we can ignore the `return this;`.  (OTOH, brevity has its own value).

Comment: "makes `delete this; return this;` stick out more"  The compiler can outright ban that, as copying and returning invalid pointer values is UB

Comment: This is a very interesting answer Yakk, like it is said in the other messages the new C++23 "deduced this" will bring a way to allow chaining, but you found another deep thing, which is the question of DRY. This could make the creation of the extension not so pointless, after all, it is not incompatible with the upcoming C++23. Well, of course the question of portability is important, so for serious projects, using the standard features is better. But learning how to develop an extension for the compiler by practicing could be useful, do you know if an extension like this is hard to create?

Comment: @BenVoigt I mean, I can make "did I delete this" be a "Rice's theorem" incomputable problem.  In trivial cases, sure.

Comment: @Morgana No, I am unaware how hard it is to modify C++ compilers to add non-trivial language extensions.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: In the cases where it "sticks out", it's easy for the compiler to detect as well.

Comment: But in the special cases where it is hard for the compiler to notice the deletion of the `this` pointer, I'm pretty sure a human may also miss it, so the presence of the `return *this` line doesn't look discordant anymore. Also, if the `return` were optional, I would have wished a compiler to emit a warning when the `this` pointer is deleted, instead of giving an error, because developers are power users, and power users want their technologies to obey them, even when the order is "break yourself".

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: If I remeber correctly, it is possible to develop an extension to some compilers without changing their code, you can pass your third-party executable (or library, I'm note sure) directly to the command line. I will try to check if it is reasonably  time-consuming. If this is not so many work, I'll do it and come here back to post it.